# Will moving my blog from blogger to wordpress affect my search engine indexing and ranking?

Tags: wordpress, seo, blogger

I currently have a blog at blogger.com with a custom domain name.  I have decided to manage my own blog using wordpress to be able to fully take advantage of all the cool wordpress plugins. Note that I am moving my domain as well. I won't be purchasing a new one.

I experimented a bit and found out that I can replicate the blogger URLs on my old blog and use the same on my new wordpress blog. For example, a Blogger URL for an article would look something like mydomain.com/this-is-my-title.htm.  Wordpress url can also be manipulated to look exactly like that.

But still, as a precaution, I want to know if this move can still affect my ranking on search engines (not that there's much to speak of) in a negative way.

Noob with SEO stuff. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do complete replication of all URLs it should not be affected at all. For the URL's that you can't mimic but you know they are indexed - set up your server to fall back to the main page of your blog.